# When concurrently filing an I-485 and I-130 does uscis.gov show an update?

Tags: usa, immigration, uscis, concurrent-i130-i485

I sent in my I-485 after e-filing an I-130 to take advantage of concurrent filing. Should I see my uscis.gov landing page updated to reflect this? If so, is there an estimation for how long it should take?

Currently the only thing I see under case status is

> Case Is Being Actively Reviewed By USCIS

[image: Case status screen shoot]

Comment: no idea, but https://www.reddit.com/r/USCIS and https://visajourney.com/forums/ likely  have an answer

Comment: I-130 an I-485 are separate applications. Could you not get the [case status](https://egov.uscis.gov/casestatus/landing.do) for your I-485 with the I-485 receipt number?

Comment: That case status link works, but is it impossible to link this to a USCIS account? I thought that was what we were supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

## Not thus far

I've received I-797C's for my I-485, I-765, and I-131. None of these I-797C's show as having been sent nor is there any other indicator of progress on my USCIS account I used to file my I-130.

---

Follow up question, [none of these had access codes so I can't link them to the account either.](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/24760/13797) **where I updated with my particular problem** tldr;

- Nothing gets updated on the my.uscis.gov sponsoring account of the US Citizen.
- The account for petitioning spouse does get updated, but only after you link the I-797c with the access code to my.uscis.gov.