# Received an I-797C with no "Access Code"?

Tags: usa, immigration, uscis

I recently received the I-797c's for my I-131, I-765, and I-485. None of these had access codes printed on them. When I go to link these into my wife's USCIS it asks for an access code. Where do I find this access code? I know I can request a new one, but what is supposed to happen here normally?

Comment: Maybe this? https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/notices/Outreach%20for%20Online%20Account%20PDF.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access code is supposed to be supplied in another letter. In my case, this letter was never sent out. I was able to request a new access code online through the interface. With the new access code I was able to link in the I-485 to my my.uscis.gov.  This linking happens not on the sponsors account (me, a US citizen), but on my wife's USCIS account.

After being linked to my wife's USCIS account, in the back of my.uscis.gov, I could see the (a) Appointment for Biometrics and the (b) Access Code document sent to the **wrong address**. In my case, they hand-entered them a `5106` street number was entered in as a `2106` street number.

Getting a new Biometrics Appointment took a simple call to (800) 375-5283, but that just puts you back in the queue. I've been waiting a month for the new appointment.